# Limit of the pair of the sequences is the pair of the limits of the sequences

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

**Exercise 1.1.16 (Tao, 2011)** *Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $(x_n)_{n=n_0}^{\infty}$ and $(y_n)_{n=n_0}^{\infty}$ be two sequences in $X$ such that $(x_n)_{n=n_0}^{\infty}$ converges to $x\in X$ and $(x_n)_{n=n_0}^{\infty}$ converges to $y \in X$ w.r.t. metric $d$. Show that
$$lim_{n\to \infty} d(x^n,y^n) = d(x,y)$$*

Proof: using the defintion of convergence in metric spaces we have to show that
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \quad \exists n_{\epsilon} \quad \forall n \geq n_{\epsilon}: \quad d(d(x^n,y^n),d(x,y)) \leq \epsilon$$
I have shown using triangle inequality that
$$d(x^n,y^n) \leq d(x^n,y) + d(y,y^n) \leq d(x^n,x) + d(x,y) + d(y,y^n) \leq 2\epsilon + d(x,y)$$
Thus
$$d(x^n,y^n) - d(x,y)\leq 2\epsilon$$
But I cannot use this fact to conclude that
$$d(d(x^n,y^n),d(x,y)) \leq 2\epsilon$$
How do I proceed then?

Comment: Flip the roles in the triangle inequality to show $d(x,y)-d(x^n,y^n)\le 2\epsilon$

Comment: Wouldn't that only prove the convergence with respect to absolute value metric?